# How can I display the elements of an array, separated by commas in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to display the elements of an array separated by commas.  Here's the code I have up to now:

```
    int[] arr = { 10, 20, 30 };
    int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
    newArray[newArray.length - 1] = 40;

    System.out.print("[ ");

    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(", " + newArray[i]);

        if (newArray.length - 1 > newArray[i])
            System.out.print(", ");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");

    }
    System.out.println("]");
```

My output is this : `[ , 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 ]`

I need to remove the comma before the first index and also not to show it after the last one.

Comment: What's wrong with `Arrays.toString()`???

Comment: Just use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));`

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] arr = { 10, 20, 30 };

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

It does the same thing you are trying to do with your algorithm.

```
Output: 
  [10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) Class

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5};
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
        for(int i : x) {
            sj.add(i + "");
        }
        System.out.println(sj);
    }
}
```

output :

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

You can also used Array Related utils Class `java.util.Arrays.toString(args);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = { 10, 20, 30 };     
        int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
        newArray[newArray.length - 1] = 40;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

better solution in your case is the dyerlin's solution.

But thinking your solution, that could be analogous a toString() implementation,

In this case, just print "," when (i == 0), just do it

```
System.out.print("[ ");
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {

      if (i > 0) {
          System.out.print(", ");
      }

      System.out.print(newArray[i]);

}
System.out.print("]");
```

Comment: Yes, thanks,  i > 0 is the correct.  Dyerlin's solution was the preview awnser System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this with Streams.

```
      int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
      };
      String arrStr = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(
            Collectors.joining(", "));

      System.out.println(arrStr);
```

You can also get the same effect by using `Arrays.toString()` and triming off the square brackets.

```
      String arrStr2 = Arrays.toString(arr);
      arrStr2 = arrStr2.substring(1,arrStr2.length()-1);
      System.out.println(arrStr2);
```

They both display.

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5